# When i set Input type in my Xml file For password My background image get changed

Tags: android, xml

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/school_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Dextro_imagelogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dextro_back" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Dextro_signup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="LOG IN"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_phone_iphone_red_a700_24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/mytext"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_vpn_key_red_a700_24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

****Whenever I try to to set Input Type for My password And Edit Text My Background Images Get Automatically get Change.Thanks In Advance
What Changes I should do Please tell me I have try every thing then also i not working for me**

Comment: you want to change or its changing?

Comment: what is your actual need please respond

Comment: its changing when i try to set input type

Comment: can you update your new xml  with the inputType